# Missing date & time applet from top Unity panel

Tags: unity, indicator

I like Unity very much. Recently, I installed Compiz manager and Nautilus Elementary also then tried to Play. During some of my playing around, Unity's clock applet has vanished.

I want to make it show the time again. How can I do this?

Comment: Because this question is "protected", I can't add this as an answer, so posting it as a comment: Another possible solution in some cases is to make sure your `~/.profile` or similar isn't setting something like `LANG=C; export LANG`... that broke this for me, *if* I had weekday or date stuff turned on (just time per se it would work).  So, I found a way to disable that line of my profile for unity config's run through my .profile, while still setting it normally (per my preference, generally), and that fixed it for me (after logout/in).

Answer (score 293):

Having date and time gone on Ubuntu 13.10 beta, after next reboot, this command solves the problem:

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: @That's working for me.

Comment: Same thing happens to me on about 1/4 of the time I boot and this is a good temporary fix.

Comment: Had to do "*sudo killall unity-panel-service*"

Comment: Why is this obvious bug still around after 2 major releases?

Comment: Solved it for me in 14

Comment: Solves problem in 14.10.

Comment: Did not directly work for me in 14.04.  Instead, I first had to run dpkg-reconfigure as in @Patryk's answer.

Comment: solves it for 14.04LTS

Comment: I had also to `/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service` and `compiz --replace` [see here](http://askubuntu.com/a/46798/46437)

Comment: This answer still works in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'm guessing this works as well but @Patyk's answer works without the need to reboot

Answer (score 60):

Reinstall `indicator-datetime`. It should be installed by default, but just in case you have removed it unknowingly, it is best to run the install command again.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

Next, we are going to reconfigure the date time:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Lastly, restart unity.

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. Running fully patched Ubuntu 13.10 on 23rd Feb 2014. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: the last command was sufficient and worked for me on 14.04

Comment: Work very well.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me, too (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: worked. Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 36):

1. Click the Ubuntu logo in the top-left.
2. Search for and open "Time and Date".
3. Open the Clock tab.
4. Make sure the box "Show a clock in menu bar" is ticked.

   [image]

Also make sure the package `indicator-datetime` is installed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when what happens on my machine (13.10) this whole tab is greyed out (albeit "Show a clock" is checked).

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio when that happens (on 14.04) I found the solution is "killall unity-panel-service".

Comment: Reinstalling `indicator-datetime` worked for me. I think I accidentally uninstalled it when I removed some `evolution` packages.

Comment: Sometimes when ubuntu base is updated and I find that date panel disappears. It will come back when I boot again. But doing  what @Stéphane suggested works for me.

Comment: For me this command worked: `pkill -f datetime`

Answer (score 19):

Double check that [`indicator-datetime` [image: Install indicator-datetime]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-datetime) is installed. Go to terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

Now log out and then back in.

Comment: In my case this was the solution. I had actually removed everything related to Evolution including the Evolution Server and somehow that relates to also removing the indicator-datetime. I simply installed all that again and it worked.

Comment: OP's requested comment: instead of logging in and out (which is slow, painful, loses your state, and smells of microsoft), you can kill unity-panel-service using `ps -ef | grep unity-panel-service` and `kill <APPROPRIATE PID>`
This will then immediately respawn a new panel service which loads the indicator.

Comment: Thanks for this, in my case I had it installed but a `apt-get purge indicator-datetime` and then and install was needed.

Answer (score 6):

On my computer, Unity shows word "Time" instead of the real time.

On Ubuntu 11 (and above?) `/etc/timezone` can't be empty (and it was). This wasn't an issue on previous versions.

To regenerate the TimeZone file just do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work you can try restoring your defaults.

From your unity session, try re-launching unity like this:

```
unity --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not found Date-Time on panel then try to find out on whether its hide or not. If not then try to find out its installed or not.

If you find that Date-Time not install then you just install it.
1. apt-get install indicator-datetime
2. killall unity-panel-service

You not need to Logoff or reset Unnity. Just check on your Desktop's Right Corner.