# How can unity-panel-service be disabled?

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, globalmenu

From the unity-panel-service manpages:

```
DESCRIPTION  
    The  unity-panel-service  program  is  normally  started automatically by the Unity
    shell (which gets started as a compiz module) and is used to draw panels which  can
    then be used for the global menu, or to hold indicators.
```

How can the unity-panel-service be non-automatically started abnormally?
In other words, how is it arbitrarily manually started and/or stopped?

The manpage implication is that this can be done without stopping the Unity shell.

This answer seems promising:

[Is it possible to restart the unity panel without restarting compiz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46788/is-it-possible-to-restart-the-unity-panel-without-restarting-compiz)

but ... not. The process can be killed from `System Monitor` but it restarts automatically.

references:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/184589/how-can-menu-bars-that-require-a-right-click-be-activated
- [How do I enable or disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)

Answer (score 4):

I used this solution to disable automatically starting unity-service-panel from starting. But you should be clear, unity-panel-service is not the panel on top bar, but it provides a service so that indicators can run on the panel.

#### Solution:

1. Move the unity-panel-service file to somewhere else

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service ~
   ```

   This will move the file to your home folder.
2. Now Logout using `Ctrl-Alt-Del` shortcut.
3. Login

The service is now disabled. If you want to verify it, run `ps -u | grep unity` in a terminal.

To revert the change, move the file back into the original location.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in Precise.
Tried:

```
    sudo mv /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service ~
```

Worked after I reversed the command and put unity-panel-service back in its original folder.  I don't understand why it would take removing the file and putting it back, for it to work.  If anyone understands why, I'm sure a lot of people would love to know.  But it works and there are absolutely no negative repercussions.

Answer (score 0):

### In Ubuntu 12.04

It is a DBUS service. It will auto launch whenever `com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service` is requested by any application and no process provide or took its ownership.

- To make it manual rename the DBUS service file:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.service.disabled
  ```
- Manual start it:

  ```
  /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service & disown $!
  ```
- Manual stop it:

  ```
  pkill -f unity-panel-service
  ```

### In Ubuntu 14.04

It's an upstart session job.

- to stop it:

  ```
  stop unity-panel-service
  ```
- start it:

  ```
  start unity-panel-service
  ```