# Is it possible to disable/enable indicator in ubuntu 16.04 VM?

Tags: command-line

How to disable/enable **indicator(status)** in ubuntu using terminal.

[image]
 If possible, please let me know.

Comment: Please, be a little bit more specific : version, Unity/Gnome ? By "indicator(status)", you mean the icon on the upper right corner ? Or the messages popping out over there ?

Answer (score 1):

You are running Unity. Maybe try, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184841/how-can-unity-panel-service-be-disabled), disabling the service providing the infos for the indicators (therefore, avoiding unity indicators to launch), type :

```
   sudo mv /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service ~/unity-panel-service.bak
```

(You basicaly move the service file to a backup file in your home directory, to undo, simply remove them tho other way around).