# How to restart unity-panel-service

Tags: unity

Sometimes, the unity panel just stops working, meaning I can't access any menus for the programs I'm running. I know I can probably log in/out but that really puts an uncomfortable hickup in my work flow.

How can I restart unity-panel when it stops working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To restart `unity-panel-service`, just run the following command in terminal:

```
kill $(pgrep unity-panel-ser)
```

Like this, the old process of `unity-panel-service` will be killed and a new one will start automatically (so you don't have to care to start yourself again).

Comment: ```kill -9 $(pgrep unity-panel-ser)``` only works for me

Comment: After `kill -9 $(pgrep unity-panel-ser)` I also had to run `compiz --replace`

Comment: This command severely messed up my GUI, and `compiz --replace` did not help. `compiz` did, but does not terminate, so now I dare not close the terminal...

Comment: `kill $(pgrep unity-panel-ser)` kills it. But it never comes back. And `unity-panel-service: command not found`. How to start it back?