# Desktop frozen and unity doesn't restart properly

Tags: unity, compiz

My desktop of 14.04 was frozen. I would like to restart without closing my running programs.

First I login into a text console by Ctrl-Alt-F1, and run a comand to restart compiz by

```
compiz --displace :0 --replace & disown
```

That brings back the windows for my running programs, but I can't switch between programs' windows by Alt-Tab (the program on the top hides other running programs' windows, so I can't use mouse to select other programs either), moving and resizing the window of the top program by Alt-Space doesn't work, and there is no dash, top panel or left panel. (Fortunately, Firefox is on the top, so I can still ask question now, but I can't access other running programs).

Then I restart unity by

```
unity &>/dev/null & disown
```

But that will take away the windows of my running programs, and only the backgroup of the desktop is shown on my screen, nothing else.

Restarting `unity-panel-serice` by [the comment here](https://askubuntu.com/a/371918/1471)doesn't work either:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep unity-panel-ser)
```

**Q:**

How shall I make my desktop normal without killing my running programs?

At least what can I try to switch between programs' windows?

Thanks.

Note:
A side problem when the desktop is frozen is: switching to a text console by ctrl-alt-F1 will take several minutes, while switching to graphical console by ctrl-alt-F7 is immediate. This side problem doesn't occur when the desktop is not frozen.

---

[Mateo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20852693#20852693) suggested me to install and run metacity, which brings back some programs' windows but not some others (including gnome terminal's window). Even

Comment: it happened to me few years ago . Maybe it could be related to an update/upgrade . My system : Samsung np530u3c ultrabook with ubuntu 14.04 x64 . I also tried Ctrl-Alt-F1 with no going to CLI no success , totally frozen system

Comment: For me, at least, restart compiz can let me see and interact with the program running on the top of the others. (That is why I can type in Firefox now, but I can't switch to other programs by Alt-tab or other mouse clicking way)

Comment: my system froze exactly when i tried to switch between programs using alt+tab , as you said not possible to click using mouse , and also not possible to go to CLI (Ctrl-Alt-F1) . So i pushed power button for few seconds to shutdown by force.

Comment: I am still possible to go to a console by Ctrl-Alt-F1

Comment: why dont you try sudo su and hit your password ? when root you can use reboot comand there

Comment: I don't want closing my running programs.