# How can I restart the Wi-Fi indicator once it disappears from the Unity top bar?

Tags: unity, wireless, indicator

Occasionally, the Wi-Fi indicator disappears from the Unity top bar.

How can I restart the Wi-Fi indicator to make the icon re-appear without having to restart my system?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, so restarting Network Manager by running `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` doesn't work for you. I guess there is something more going on.

Comment: Indeed, it successfully restores my wireless connection but it does not bring back the top bar icon for the wireless indicator.

Comment: There is some guidance at http://askubuntu.com/questions/46788/is-it-possible-to-restart-the-unity-panel-without-restarting-compiz. Maybe give it a shot?

Comment: Good idea but restarting the entire panel did not bring back the wireless icon either.

Comment: Maybe can try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/475579/15003).

Comment: Sadly no again. Is there any way I can restart indicators individually?