# Network manager and indicators missing from the top panel (Ubuntu 16.04 Unity)

Tags: unity, 16.04, network-manager, indicator

A few days ago, while I was doing some network configuration tests, I went offline.

At first I did not realize, but all indicators (cpu, memory, ...) even the one of the network manager disappeared from the top panel...

Using a USB live, I reinstalled network-manager, but I'm still unable to see the icon.

The indicators are also running, but they're not visible (same as the network manager).

How can I get them back visible in the top panel?

Comment: I bring back several icons (included network manager),  with 'killall unity-panel-service' [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46788/is-it-possible-to-restart-the-unity-panel-without-restarting-compiz) but I'm still unable to see the CPU, memory... indicators

Answer (score 2):

I find the network indicator sometimes disappears in 16.04 with unity after restarting network-manager  (`systemctl restart NetworkManager`) as above. What seems to be happening is that the nm-applet is crashing

Try running (using alt-f2, terminal would work too but then you have to remember not to close that terminal)

`nm-applet`

Sometimes you may also need to restart the unity panel as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46788/is-it-possible-to-restart-the-unity-panel-without-restarting-compiz)

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/46788/is-it-possible-to-restart-the-unity-panel-without-restarting-compiz
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04; it happens occasionally or when resuming from suspend. A fix that worked for me is to open the terminal and type:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

This fixes it immediately.

Comment: This sometimes works, but only for the WiFi indicator...

Comment: You can also add a script for systemd with the previous code for resume/suspend and It works fine with me but I believe it would require gksudo or something

Comment: I had the same symptoms on 18.04 after suspend. Your workaround works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug with the Wifi indictor icon disappearing in Ubuntu 16.04 since May 2016.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/1585886

Comment: Unclear if it's the same bug - seems only to affect wifi