# Time indicator is not showing the date/time

Tags: indicator

Yesterday I noticed that time indicator on the top pane is not showing the date/time, but is just saying "Time" (see attached screenshot). Does anyone know why is that so? How can I fix it and make show the date/time back again?

Reinstalling indicator-datetime did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that the indicator is misconfigured.

Try to click *Time & Date settings* in your screenshot, in the next window choose clock and play with those settings.

If this doesn't work try this command, it will change the potenciall most complicated of your clock settings to the defaults:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format locale-default
```

Answer (score 4):

Can I suggest you right click the click and choose *Time & Date Settings*

Check that you have a valid location set (the field and the graphic point to your country and capital city etc).

Also check the next tab that the defaults are defined as per this image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

From: [Missing date & time applet from top Unity panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-from-top-panel-of-unity-desktop)

Comment: Thanks! This answer fixed it for me, when the others did not.