# Menu bar shows the word "Time" where current time should be

Tags: 12.04, time, clock, panel

I just upgraded from 10.10 to 12.04.  A picture says a thousand words in this case.  Here's a G+ post with a screenshot of my menu bar:

[image]

I've tried messing with the clock settings---specifying a time zone, un-checking & re-checking "show a clock in the menu bar", and asking that "weekday" and "date and month" be displayed with the time.  Nothing seems to work.  Any ideas how I can get the actual clock to display instead of the word "Time"?  Thanks.

Requested system information:

```
jason@pinot:~$ gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format
'%l:%M %p'
```

Comment: please open aTerminal window, run `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format` and post its output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Launchpad bug #863341](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/863341) has the solution to my issue:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

After I ran the above command, "Time" disappeared and the current time is now displayed in my menu bar.  The bug also notes that this [question has previously been discussed on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-from-top-panel-of-unity-desktop).