# How to get a clock in Unity top panel?

Tags: unity, 12.10, panel, clock

I installed Ubuntu 12.10, 64-bit, I had a clock up in the top right of the top menu panel.

I noticed the other day that it is no longer there.  I've scoured all the settings and everything in Ubuntu Tweak, but I can't find any way to get it back.

How do I get my clock back on Unity top panel?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking System settings->Time & date->Clock->Show clock in menu bar? If that doesn't do anything, is the package `indicator-datetime` is installed (ie try reinstalling it)?

Comment: @mtdevans  I'd add that as a answer :)

Comment: Answer for Ubuntu 13.10 on this link:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-from-top-panel-of-unity-desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, try checking it's installed with `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime`.

Also, check the setting's checked at `System Settings->Time & Date->Clock`:

[image]

Comment: Yeaup, that worked! For some reason it was no longer installed. Thank you very much!