# Clock does not appear in the Panel

Tags: panel, time

I can't make the clock show in the Panel. I also can't change my clock settings in *All Settings* -> *Time & Date* -> *Clock* tab. They are all blocked. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What does that mean? Please take time to write an answerable question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a clock in Unity top panel?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/260823/how-to-get-a-clock-in-unity-top-panel)

Comment: @ElderGeek I think the issue here is that the options are greyed out, unlike the possible dupe that you linked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen as well; usually after a fresh install of 14.04. Normally it resolves itself after a reboot (or 2, at the most). Never did find a literal fix except ... rebooting.