# Missing date & time from top panel of Unity Desktop - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, indicator, 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 an my machine and since the last upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 the date&time is missing in the top panel of Unity. This machine was originally installed with Ubuntu 12.10. I upgraded it from 12.10→13.04, from 13.04→13.10 and last week from 13.10→14.04.

I tried every solution found in this question: [Missing date & time from top panel of Unity Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-from-top-panel-of-unity-desktop). But nothing of all this works :-(

I tried the following things:

- reinstalling `indicator-datetime`
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge indicator-datetime` and install it again
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata`
- `sudo killall unity-panel-service`

and of course log out/log in again and so on...

Where can I find log files for the indicator or where could help me otherwise with this problem?

Trying to debug:

```
$ locate indicator-datetime-service
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
Indicator-Datetime-Message: indicator-datetime exiting; failed/lost bus ownership
```

Comment: `locate indicator-datetime-service` to find where it is installed then run it in terminal. Report if there any error message.

Comment: @Sneetsher 

    $ locate indicator-datetime-service
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service

    $ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
    Indicator-Datetime-Message: indicator-datetime exiting; failed/lost bus ownership
    $ sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service

no error output, when running indicator-datetime-service with sudo

Comment: `failed/lost bus ownership` means it was running already.

Comment: try reseting its configuration `dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/` . didn't work try `pkill -f datetime` then `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service`

Comment: dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/

worked and it shows the time again. But I think I found a bug and I think I know what causes the issue. Are there any logs for the datetime-indicator to verify my assumption?

Comment: well.. the only info I could find is making a link to/copy of `/usr/share/libindicator/80indicator-debugging` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` but I am not sure which log (may be `/var/log/syslog` like session logging). (info source: `dpkg -L libindicator3-tools`)

Comment: You Could try downloading unity tweak tool. Then go to the panel menu, you should see date and time options there.

Answer (score 138):

Try reseting its configuration

```
dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/
```

If it didn't show up try kill it, it should restart

```
pkill -f datetime
```

---

For similar cases, better to explain how you may get it:

1. Check if it is running, if yes then possibly a configuration problem

   ```
   $ ps ax | grep -i indicator-datetime
    2863 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
    4043 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep -i indicator-datetime
   ```
2. Check for where is its configuration. Look for `/etc/` or `dconf` in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`. List package files using:

   ```
   $ dpkg -L indicator-datetime
   [...]
   /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-datetime.desktop
   /usr
   /usr/share
   /usr/share/glib-2.0
   /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
   /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.indicator.datetime.gschema.xml
   [...]
   ```
3. Locate its dconf path:

   ```
   $ grep path /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.indicator.datetime.gschema.xml
       <schema id="com.canonical.indicator.datetime" path="/com/canonical/indicator/datetime/" gettext-domain="indicator-datetime">
   ```

Comment: the dconf reset did it for me, thx

Comment: I had the same problem after resetting 14.04 and your "dconf reset" did it for me, thanks +1

Comment: `dconf` didn't help, but `pkill` did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks the dconf reset worked, i didn't even need to kill the datetime process

Comment: dconf didn't work for me but pkill did on my Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Warning: the `dconf` trick doesn't just restore the clock. It also resets your clock settings, so if you have customized them... goodbye to your settings. I wish I hadn't tried that -- `pkill datetime` had already restored the clock to my UI.

Comment: @Lambart , yes it does reset all datetime settings, but that seems not a big deal for most users.

Comment: The command dconf reset and killing the process after that did the trick for me, thank you!

Answer (score 20):

I had exactly the same problem, which that some Language Support libraries are missing.

If you go to:

**Settings** → **Language Support**

The system will automatically update the regional formats and the time and date will be back after you log out and in.

Comment: Tried, but there was no missing language support

Comment: Actually, weird as it sounds, I can confirm this solution. Apparently starting the langauge support panel, some broken libs are indeed (i guess not downloaded but) reenabled. Therefore a +1

Comment: the datetime indicator uses a calendar which requires specific language based format. It seems that it's suffice to take the indicator down :)

Answer (score 20):

This worked with me when I faced the same problem:

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

without 'sudo' by the way.

Comment: +1 I had the missing-clock-problem a few times already, and this worked reliably as an immediate fix. For the record,  `indicator-datetime` is installed on my machine, so apparently no need to remove/purge it for me.

Comment: +1solved [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1228360)

Answer (score 1):

Just kill the indicator-datetime-service process. (This process will get started automatically)

For ex:

```
$ ps ax | grep -i indicator-datetime
2863 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
4043 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep -i indicator-datetime

kill -9 <pid-of-indicator-datetime-service>
kill -9 2863
```

Answer (score 0):

Under System Settings, open *Time & Date*. Choose the *Clock* tab to the right of the *Time & Date* tab. Check *Show a clock in the menu bar*.

Under *In the clock, show*, select Weekday, Date and Month, Year or whichever of those you want.

Comment: The clock tab is greyed out for me - I can't edit the settings there....

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `indicator-datetime` doesn't remove configuration files and settings under `Clock` will be grayed out. Doing `sudo apt-get purge indicator-datetime; sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime; kill -9 -1;` will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

i have been trying to fix my time and language icon missing on the panel.
i tried many commands but no use but i finally found myself

click alt+right mouse on the panel

click add to panel

double click on indicator applet complete


your missing icons could be recovered, i had successed by this methode

Comment: please read this

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and was facing the same issue. I tried all above-mentioned solution but still facing the same problem.
I resolved the problem by deleting file "libxm2.so.2" file from the location "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2".
First, check if the same file exists at multiple locations on your system. If yes then delete all except from "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2"
 Warning: Please backup before deleting this file to avoid any other system issue.