# Clock disappears after trying to add Weekday / Date

Tags: 14.04, indicator, clock

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and when I try to add "Weekday" or "Date and month" to my clock, the entire clock disappears (though, oddly this does not happen when I add "Seconds"). I tried to uninstall and reinstall indicator.datetime, but no luck. Any tips?

Before:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwTfJ.png)

After:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zEaj.png)

Comment: Have you tried relogging after the change ?

Comment: I should have clarified, but yes, I have.

Comment: It might not be very helpful, but it works for me x) So it might be a random issue, or a conflict? Can't do much more for you, sorry. Other may!

Comment: There is another question with some answers that you might try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458117/missing-date-time-from-top-panel-of-unity-desktop-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

Ok, install dconf:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

open dconf under *com>canonical>indicator>datetime*:

and uncheck and check " show-clock ".

logout and login.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by

1. deleting the `/etc/locale.conf`
2. Going to Settings -> Language Support -> Regional Formats; choose a format; and 'Apply System-Wide'
3. reboot

Background: The problem appeared when I changed my locale settings globally in /etc/locale.conf instead of locally in .bashrc. A post on [Missing date & time from top panel of Unity Desktop - Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458117) pointed to 'Settings -> Language Support'. But only installing the missing regional formats was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to comment out (remove) line `export LC_ALL=C` in `/etc/environment`.

1. Logout
2. Login
3. Enable weekend/date in clock settings