# Clock doesn't show AM/PM anymore

Tags: unity, 16.04, time, clock

My new install of 16.04 doesn't have AM/PM anymore in the clock on the top right. 12 hour time is checked in System Settings. How do I get AM/PM back?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the effective locale for the `LC_TIME` locale category is one which misses AM/PM specification. To fix it you can [change the Regional Formats setting](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html). If you change it to e.g. *English (United States)* or *English (United Kingdom)*, AM/PM will show up next time you log in.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. Still no AM/PM :(

Comment: @Vistaus: Really? Then can you please open a terminal window, run the `locale` command, and let us know the output by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonably straightforward to toggle this setting from the clock settings. (*Note: I realise that you have already followed this path but best to check.*)

Follow this path:

```
Click on the clock > Time & date settings... > Clock
```

And from here select 12 hour time as illustrated in this screenshot:

[image]

If this is not enough and the clock is still not obeying your needs try running the following commands:

1. Reinstall the clock

   ```
   sudo apt-get --reinstall install indicator-datetime
   ```
2. Reconfigure the date/time

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
   ```
3. Reset the 'unity-panel-service'

   ```
   killall unity-panel-service
   ```

And this may be enough to reload the offending clock and tweak it into obeying your preferred settings..

*Note: These tips will have no effect if your current locale does not support AM/PM as Gunnar Hjalmarsson has pointed out...*

**References:**

- https://askubuntu.com/a/399178/57576

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation, and all comments on this post, have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42583/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-46-clock-doesnt-show-am-pm-anymore).