# Indicator Datetime Service crash (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, unity

I am using Unity on Ubuntu 20.04 for a couple of weeks and suddenly the time indicator on the service panel disappeared a couple of days ago. Tried all the answers provided on the web but was unable to restore the time indicator.

When I ran locate indicator-datetime-service, I found a couple of crash files:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service

/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-datetime_indicator-datetime-service.1000.crash

/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-datetime_indicator-datetime-service.1000.upload

/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-datetime_indicator-datetime-service.1000.uploaded

### The snippet of the crash file is shown below

ProblemType: Crash

Architecture: amd64

CrashCounter: 1

CurrentDesktop: Unity:Unity7:ubuntu

Date: Fri May 28 23:07:13 2021

DistroRelease: Ubuntu 20.04

ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-
service

ExecutableTimestamp: 1581950243

ProcCmdline: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser
vice

---

Is there something I can do to fix the problem?

Regards,
hoongshen

Comment: Got a similar problem, indicator-datetime-service is consuming ram and cpu until the system is freezed. The only thing that helps - is killing it.

Comment: I concur with Patrik Novak.  Setting the niceness to +19 using htop *press the F8 button 19 times) delayed the onset of the problem but did not stop it.  I'm a little curious why the Out Of Memory (OOM) killer didn't or doesn't kill it, but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have any update? I'm still stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

indicator-datetime-service

Collapse the RAM and CPU
see in System Monitor (Processes: indicator-datetime-service 'stop it')

Open 'Online Accounts' from System Tools, Software (program repositories)
Select the Google Online Account and disable calendar synchronization.

This was my problem too on Ubuntu Mate 20.04

[google acount online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77KUb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
Check System Monitor -> Search 'indicator-datetime-service'-> if you find it then disable it.
Then go to online accounts and then disable calendar synchronization and then follow the steps of the 2nd answer of  [Missing date & time applet from top Unity panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-applet-from-top-unity-panel) .

Then restart and log in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).