# indicator-datetime-service stopped working

Tags: 20.04, indicator, evolution, calendar, gnome-flashback

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME Flashback. Just recently I noticed that my computer suddenly had a very high CPU load, I was hearing fans running very loud and the GUI noticeably slowed down and was unresponsive.

After investigation I found out that the process `indicator-datetime-service`, which displays current time in my top bar, uses 100% of the CPU and eats up RAM very quickly, using more and more GBs. Also, the service is unable to "pull" the events from online calendar(s) I have configured in Evolution - normally, after clicking the clock, a calendar table was displayed with all events from online calendar marked, but this is no more the case - no events are marked.

The behavior is very similar to described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341333/indicator-datetime-service-crash-ubuntu-20-04), and in the linked question the problem was not solved.

Because this happened shortly after some packages were updated (in particular perl and python packages plus SSH library), I downgraded all these packages to their previous versions, but this did not fix the problem. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall `indicator-datetime-service` package, also to no avail. Just to be sure, I rebooted the computer after each install/uninstall, but this did not change anything.

I don't know which might have caused the problem as I was working on my computer the whole day without any CPU overload issues, and this happened just recently. Except of upgrade, the only thing I did just before that happened that may be related to the problem was I updated my calendar in Evolution. Maybe Evolution did "break" something on close, but what exactly and how to revert it?

For now, the only option for me was to disable the `indicator-datetime-service`. I was able to replace it with another clock applet in the top bar, but I'm not fully satisfied with this one, as it has problems if I set it to display only the time, without the date - which is what I prefer.

Does anybody have any idea what I can do to restore the correct functionality?